# Riemann's Sphere Scale Factor

Tags: trigonometry

If we considered Riemann's sphere as a stereographic projection to get a sphere onto a [planar surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydmn0.png). I'm pretty sure these are this is the [right formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynwsq.png) from what I've seen, but I'd like to confirm that this is the case. My main question is how one could find the scale factor of Riemann's sphere (i.e. the ratio between how much a distance is on the map in proportion to that of the sphere). I've seen that they have done it this study, but I think it might be wrong or at least it seems wrong when I put it in desmos(https://sci-hub.mksa.top/10.1080/07468342.2001.11921900).

Comment: The name is Riemann. Bernhard Riemann.

Comment: thanks, I keep spelling it both ways for whatever reason.

Comment: Can you explain in the question what you think is wrong with the answer in the link? Having the question be self contained without having to go through the link will help whoever wants to answer.

Comment: They give the answer csc^2(long/2). This seems wrong since when I put it in desmos there is a vertical asymtote on 0 degree, but a longitude of 0 degrees is very much representable on the projection, it is somewhat stretched, but very much there.